# How do I make a continuous smoothed median with ggplot function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, median, smoothing

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, colour = factor(cyl)))+
geom_point(stat = "identity")+
theme_bw()+
geom_smooth()
```

Instead of getting a continuous smoothed median, I get what looks like a fractured and inaccurate of the median of the data as a whole. I think this is due to the "factor(cyl)" function.

Here is a link to what my code gives:

[image: diagram of output]

Comment: since your data are grouped by `factor(cyl)`, all subsequent geom use this grouping, even `geom_smoothed`. Maybe you want something like this : `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg))+
  geom_point(stat = "identity",aes(colour = factor(cyl)))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_smooth()` ; the colors will only be applied to the points, though, not to the lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If add aes(group=1) in the geom_smooth() you will fix your problem:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, colour = factor(cyl)))+
 geom_point(stat = "identity")+
 theme_bw()+
 geom_smooth(aes(group=1))
```